# How to see the learning of a classifier over time?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, dataset, scikit-learn, fitting

I am a beginner,

I try to find out if it is possible to know "where the classifier stands" in its learning.

Indeed I have a lot of data and after doing `clf.fit(X,y)` with scikit-Learn it takes a lot of time and I don't have the possibility to monitor the learning to see if it is ending soon or not.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Before calling fit, try adding `verbose=True` or `verbose=1` to the classifier. This will probably not work with all of sklearn's models.